# Get cookie from website using volley

Tags: android, cookies, android-volley

I'm trying to get an identification cookie sent from a website, and for this i'm using [Volley library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

First of all, yes i have searched this subject extensively for the past couple of days and using all the answers i managed to rack up this code:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
StringRequest stringRequest = null;
RequestQueue queue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bauth);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String url = "http://daviddurand.info/D228/pizza/?action=login&user=david";
            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
                            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
                            try {
                                Log.d("URI 1", manager.getCookieStore().get(new URI("http://daviddurand.info/D228/pizza/?action=login&user=david")).toString());
                            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.d("URIS", manager.getCookieStore().getURIs().toString());
                            Log.d("COOKIE", manager.getCookieStore().getCookies().toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //error
                }
            });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Which does not return anything more than empty brackets, so i'm guessing something(s) wrong..
For starters am i heading the right way here? and what exactly do i need to add to make this work?

Comment: Yikes.  I think you would have to make a custom `Request` subclass that would return both the server data and the cookies.  I wouldn't trust the `CookieManager` to have the updated cookies at the exact time that I requested them.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to put this:

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

in your response. but only once before you start making calls.

Using CookieHandler HttpURLConnection, which apparently is the http stack you use :), takes care of the cookies so you need to take care of that in Volley itself.

so you can do

`CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));`

just before `queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`